# Можно ли сказать "стань уверенна и неотразима" или это ошибка?

Tags: глаголы, грамматика

Можно ли написать "стань уверенна и неотразима"? Грамотно ли это? Уверенна и неотразима в этом случае какие части речи?

Справедливо ли замечание, что при повелительном наклонении глагола Стань используется прилагательное, а не наречие. Т.е. "Стань уверенной", а не "стань уверенна"?

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, где я могу найти правило на эту тему?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант можно оставить: стань уверенна и неотразима. Здесь используется составное именное сказуемое, где СТАТЬ - полузнаменательная связка.

Именную часть можно выразить двумя способами: (1) полной формой прилагательного в Т.п. (уверенной, неотразимой) и (2) краткой формой прилагательного (уверенна, неотразима).

Первый вариант (стань какой?) обозначает временность, переходность признака в соответствии со значением глагола, и  этот вариант является НЕЙТРАЛЬНЫМ.

Второй вариант  можно считать ОТКЛОНЕНИЕМ от нормы, но такое отклонение придает высказыванию дополнительную экспрессию.Сравнить: Лицо станет каменным/лицо станет каменное.

Таким образом, предлагаемое выражение можно считать авторским вариантом.

Answer (score 1):

"Стань уверенна и неотразима" - вполне нормальная фраза, где "уверенна и неотразима" - это краткие прилагательные, которые в данном случае надо поставить в именительном падеже. А вот если бы эти прилагательные были полными, то тогда следовало бы употребить творительный падеж (стань уверенной и неотразимой). 
   При повелительном наклонении глагола, конечно, употребляется в приведенной фразе прилагательное (стань уверенной), но может быть и наречие, но только не тот пример, который Вы привели (стань уверенна - это не наречие, а краткое прилагательное). Пример с наречием: "стань уверенно смотрящей в будущее"

Comment: Ну, вообще вас об этом испрашивают: можно ли использовать краткую форму (или это ошибка, это неграмотно)? Х..ле рассуждать, если не знаете ответа?

Comment: Уважаемый Михаил! Прежде чем делать некорректное замечание (мягко сказано), следует внимательно прочесть первую же фразу моего ответа, где четко дан ответ на поставленный вопрос. Вообще, я был о Вас более высокого мнения, пока не прочитал только что опубликованный комментарий.

Comment: Человек забылся, где он.